# Change Sorted List Background color

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-color

I am currently woking on a small navigation in HTML using CSS.
I have a sorted List with every li element Containing a  link.
I want it to change the background color, when hovering over it. The problem is, that the number telling you the index of the list item won't get changed because "this" background is not part of the li element. [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style_colors)

[image: ProblemDesc]

The ol element, which "owns" this background is the whole list, but I just want that the background of this specific list entry gets changed.
My code is:

```
.navig a:hover{
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

and

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="target.php">target</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The navig class is used to make clear that the link belongs to the navigation.

Is there a way to fix this without JScript, or belongs this to the missing "CSS support for parent selecting" thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list-style-position: inside;` to move the numbers / bullet into the `li` element:

```css
ol {
  background: #ff9999;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  padding: 5px;
}
li:hover {
  background: #ffe5e5;
}
li > a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.il/search?q=coffee">Coffee</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.il/search?q=tea">Tea</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.il/webhp?q=coca+cola">Coca Cola<a>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution as described [here](https://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/) is to convert your list into a DL/DT list and explicitly generate the numbers using a CSS counter.

```css
.navig {
  counter-reset: navig-counter;
}
.navig dt:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
.navig dt:before {
  content: counter(navig-counter);
  counter-increment: navig-counter;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="navig">
  <dt><a href="#">First item</a></dt>
  <dt><a href="#">Second item</a></dt>
  <dt><a href="#">Third item</a></dt>
</dl>
```